# Error while using socialite in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Whenever i try try to use `Socialite::driver('facebook')->user()`  in callback this error shows up!

> No system CA bundle could be found in any of the the common system locations.
>   PHP versions earlier than 5.6 are not properly configured to use the system's
>   CA bundle by default.

Comment: This is a problem with PHP's configuration on your server not your Laravel code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my ssl extension. I solved it downloading fresh cacert.pem and linking it to php.ini file .